# Fastreport DBCross View

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have DBCross Table contain string and integer data
I would like to change the color of the row through specific 
condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the PrintCell event of DBCross component, and check the value

```
procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if value < 1000 then           
    Memo.Color := clRed                                                       
end;
```

as you can see Memo is just TfrxMemoView, so you can change any properties of TfrxMemoView such as font, style and color.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed Nasman, but this should effect only one cell
I want to check first cell if it's match then change the color for the entire row

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the font appearance and/or background color of a cell based on a specific condition, you have a more simple option of using the highlight function.  It is located at the 2nd line of the quick icon with "ab" and a pen with highlight.  You can specify a condition and what appearance and background color you want that cell to change into.

But for more complex operation like multiple conditions and the like, the answer by Mohammed will be the most robust way to handle them.

For changing whole row based on 1 value you have 2 options using Mohammed code :

1 . Change the

```
if value < 1000 then
```

to

```
if <DataSet."FieldName"> < 1000 then
```

and then assigned the event to every cell's BeforePrint for that row.

2 . Change the

```
Memo.Color := red
```

to

```
begin 
  Cell1Memo.Color := clRed; 
  Cell2Memo.Color := clRed,
  ...
end;
```